# .Net7 Isolated Azure SignalR SignalRMessageAction outside of trigger

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-signalr

How do I send a system generated signalr  message from the Azure Function itself instead of from a trigger?

The following statement, outside of a trigger, does not generate an error but it does not reach the listeners.

```cs
return new SignalRMessageAction("newMessage") {Arguments = new[] { "Sample Message" }};
```

With InProcess Azure SignalR Function, I could, from inside c# code, send a message by adding a new SignalRMessage to IAsyncCollector

```cs
signlRMsg = new SignalRMessage{Target = "myTarget",Arguments = new[] { "Sample Message"}};
await _signalRMessages.AddAsync(signalRMessage);//IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each function should have a trigger, otherwise we have no way to trigger the function. In in-process model, you can only get an `IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage>` in a function with a trigger.

So, I'm not sure what you mean by "outside of a trigger". Do you mean "outside of a SignalR trigger"? If so, the answer is yes. `SignalRMessageAction` is the one of the return types of SignalR output binding, and you can combine it with any type of triggers. Please see [an example of sending a SignalR message triggered by HTTP request](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-output?tabs=isolated-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#broadcast-to-all-clients).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an instance of type ***ServiceHubContext***.
That type exposes methods like .Clients.All.Send(@your message);
Also you need to register the type so it becomes available throughout your application code. You can use a HostedService for that you have registered as a singleton.

```
 public class SignalRService : IHostedService
 {
 private const string MessageHub = "Hub";
 private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
 private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

 public ServiceHubContext MessageHubContext { get; private set; }

 public SignalRService(IConfiguration configuration, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
 {
     _configuration = configuration;
     _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
 }

 async Task IHostedService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     using var serviceManager = new ServiceManagerBuilder()
         .WithOptions(o => o.ConnectionString = _configuration["AzureSignalRConnectionString"])
         .WithLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory)
         .BuildServiceManager();
     MessageHubContext = await serviceManager.CreateHubContextAsync(MessageHub, cancellationToken);
 } ...
```

Then inside program.cs register it with

```
s.AddSingleton<SignalRService>();
s.AddHostedService(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<SignalRService>());
```

Then inject SignalRService and use its 'MessageHubContext' property